# Defining a 2 dimensional char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char, 2d

I've been struggling with switching from Java to C as far as objects and arrays are concerned. To pretext my question I've been tasked to create a Conway's life simulator. My issue is that when I'm trying to create an object **Generation** which contains the current board as a 2 dimensional char array and the generation number like this:

```
struct GENERATION
{
    char board[][];
    int numGen;
};

typedef struct GENERATION Generation;
```

I get an error from the compiler:

```
Conway's Game of Life.c:6:15: error: array has incomplete element type 'char []'
```

So my question is: How do I create an uninitialized 2D char array within a struct and be able to change the contents of that object?

Comment: An array must have static bounds. In other words, you need to specify the size of the array. If those are not known at compile time, you need to allocate the memory dynamically into a `char**`. What you have there is not a valid construct in C.

Comment: You should consult a C book to learn the language. C is definitively a very bad thing to learn by trial&error. As a starter: C "objects" are very different from what typical OOPL call "objects".

Comment: @DeiDei: a `char **` cannot hold a 2D array! Don't lay wrong traces. The only thing correct is that OP needs a pointer. But to a `char (*)[COLS]`, not a `char **`!

Comment: Put numbers inside the `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C must have their size specified as part of the declaration.  You'll either have to use fixed-size arrays in your `GENERATION` type, as in:

```
#define ROWS 20
#define COLS 30

struct GENERATION
{
  char board[ROWS][COLS];
  int numGen;
};
```

or you'll have to allocate the `board` member dynamically at runtime.

The most straightforward method is to allocate a 1D array of `char`, large enough to hold `rows` by `cols` elements:

```
struct GENERATION
{
  char *board;
  int numGen;
};

size_t rows = ...;
size_t cols = ...;

GENERATION g;
g.board = malloc( sizeof *g.board * rows * cols );
```

You'd then index into `board` as

```
g.board[i * rows + j] = ' ';
```

You'll need to be sure to deallocate the `board` member before `g` goes out of scope (or is deallocated if you dynamically allocated it), otherwise you'll have a memory leak:

```
free( g.board );
```

If the rows of your array don't have to be contiguous, you could do a piecemeal allocation that kind of sort of looks like a 2D array if you turn the lights down a bit:

```
struct GENERATION
{
  char **board;
  int numGen;
};

GENERATION g;
g.board = malloc( sizeof *g.board * rows );
if ( g.board )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    g.board[i] = malloc( sizeof *g.board[i] * cols );
}
```

And you'd index into it as

```
g.board[i][j] = ' ';
```

Again, you'll need to deallocate `board` before `g` goes out of scope:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
  free( g.board[i] );
free( g.board );
```

Unfortunately, you can't use variable-length arrays (VLAs) as `struct` members; otherwise this would be a lot easier.